# How to get all the department stores present in a city in android using google places?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

Hi I have developed an app which uses google-places API to get the list of nearby department stores. This works perfectly and I am using [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) tutorial to get the places, but now I need to add one more functionality to this ie; is it possible to get the details of all the department stores present in a particular city, if so how to do this.

If it is not possible, how to go about it. I have searched the internet, but I have not able to find anything useful.

```
To summarize I need to have 3 buttons in my app. 
1. Displays the map which displays the nearby department stores.
2. Displays the nearby stores in the form of a list.
3. Displays the list of stores in a particular city.
```

I am new to Android and don't understand how to do all the above. I would appreciate if anyone can guide me or post some tutorials.

Thanks.

Comment: that would assume all that information is even available, which I seriously doubt. They may list SOME stores, but not all, certainly not for ALL cities.

Comment: i know what i want is right now it is taking my latitude and longitude and displaying the places which are inside a radius of 3000m but i want to add another button which enables me to display the stores which are there in the whole city.

Comment: I thought of increasing the range but it'll display the stores which are already there and also it limits the places to 20places in a page and total of 60 places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better to maintain another database( your own ) for your app. In your database store all types of information including latitude and longitude. Then query on your database from your app. you can use JSON parser to retrieve data from database.

Happy Coding